# PHP- MYSQL A non-numeric value encountered

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to search and display the data from phpmyadmin by using the keyword ID2 which is a number .I try to convert the input take from front-end page into to int to use the SEARCH function in PHP to work. But it keeps showing the warning A non-numeric value encountered.

Here is the code from the front-end page

```
<input type="number" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search by ID" class="input is-primary is-rounded" />
```

Here is the code that i used to convert the input take from the front-end and then used with the SEARCH function in PHP

```
$search_num = (int)$_POST['search'];
        echo mysqli_error($connect); 
        if ($stmt = $connect->prepare('SELECT * FROM fruitinfo WHERE ID2 LIKE '%$search_num%'')) {
```

Comment: Where and when do you get that error? And why do you have `echo mysqli_error($connect);`? Why are you using `LIKE` here? What does the column `ID2` contain? Please give us some more context.

Comment: i use Xdebug in vscode and its show the error. And this echo mysqli_error($connect); i used to debug. The ID2 containt number only

Comment: You still need to update your question with way more info. It's too unclear why you are doing what you are doing. We don't know what the columns contain or what this suppose to do or why you're doing what you're doing. Also, when I ask where it happens, I mean exactly where in the code you get that error.

Comment: The error i get from Xbug happens at this line `if ($stmt = $connect->prepare('SELECT * FROM fruitinfo WHERE ID2 LIKE '%$search_num%'')) `

Comment: Ah... Now I see the issue. The error shouldn't be a mysql error but rather a PHP syntax error. If you change your quoting for the query to use double quotes around it: `"SELECT ... LIKE '%$search_num%'"` it will work much better.

Comment: oh it's working right now. Thank you @MagnusEriksson